# Discrete Fourier Transform, overly large zero-frequency term

Tags: fourier-transform, data-analysis

After looking around this website and many others, I've been able to figure out most of how to reconstruct my time-domain data by using the discrete fourier transform. (http://www-elsa.physik.uni-bonn.de/~dieckman/DFT/DFT.html was quite helpful.)

BUT: I cannot figure out why the s=1 term of my transformed frequency data is so overly large when compared to the rest. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647690/discrete-fourier-transform-problem) describes that the first term is an average of the data, but then the value should be approximately 1/50th of what the DFT yields.

Here's a snippet of the first bit of the time domain and resultant frequency domain vectors:

Time: {0.12545, 0.093577, 0.083911, 0.07649, 0.080237, 0.112101, 0.112242, 0.137024, 0.143058, 0.131691, 0.117775, 0.096736, 0.08467, 0.078244, 
0.08896, 0.099834, …}

(modulus of) Frequency: {**2.87325**, 0.0447267, 0.0945387, 0.0535332, 0.0138847, 0.0161506, 0.0278486, 0.0229005, 0.0912012, 0.0123259, 0.03707, 0.0396228, 0.0781733, 0.0263154, 0.0117688, …}

My data is has n=500, timestep=1. I've been working with the data in Mathematica, but I don't believe the issue is with how I'm using Mathematica.

I'm really at a loss as to what would be causing such a huge offset frequency term. If I ignore it and just try to determine the shift manually, everything works fine! But...that's not good practice. I also had to omit it when calculating the periods of my modes, which isn't good practice either. So any explanations as to why the real-frequency is abnormally large and/or suggestions on how to approach it would be welcomed!

Comment: What is the sum of your 500 time-domain points?

Comment: The sum of the time domain points is 64.2477, which is actually a number I recognize as the zero-frequency term from when I did the FT with parameters {1,-1}.

So it is related to that sum, somehow. I tried to take the average manually, and that does yield a number very similar to the one I originally generalized as the shift. So that question helped a lot.

My question now, is....why is it showing up as the sum and not the average, mathematically?

Comment: The paper you cite uses a $\sqrt n$ scaling.  Accordingly, the 0 frequency term should be $64.2477/\sqrt{500}=2.87324$, which is pretty much what your report as the result.  So I don't understand your question: the 0 freq component seems to be exactly what you'd expect.

Comment: I think the default FT scaling used by Mathematica is the $\sqrt n$ scaling you observe.  The post you mention in your 2nd paragraph uses $n$ scaling.  Whenever I use an FT software for the first time, I check it on test cases to make sure the scaling and sign in the exponent are as I expect.

Comment: So just to ensure I'm understanding this correctly:
The first term is a sum of all of the numbers in my time vector because the weighting factor of the exponential will equal 1, since s=1 --> e^0, whereas for all other terms the weighting factor is obviously much less than 1. 

I guess what I need to look into is why there are different scalings, where you say Mathematica uses the sqrt(n) scaling and apparently my data requires an n scaling to match with the other frequency data output by the FT? It's at least a place for me to focus on, thank you!

Comment: No. The paper you cite (http://www-elsa.physik.uni-bonn.de/~dieckman/DFT/DFT.html) gives a formula, which as far as I know is what your computer evaluated.  The a-th frequency is the sum of the b-th data point times a term of form exp(2pi*i*a*b/500) divided by sqrt(500).  In the special case of the 0-th frequency this reduces to the sum of the data values, divided by sqrt(500).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @kimchi lover, I think I'm able to understand what is going on now.

Mathematica uses the formula
$$
v_s=\frac{1}{n^{1/2}}\sum^n_{n=1}u_r e^{2\pi i(r-1)(s-1)n}
$$
to evaluate the Fourier Transform of the time domain vector $u_r$, which yields a vector of equal length containing frequencies, $v_s$. The zeroth frequency, at $v_1$, is equal to $\frac{1}{n^{1/2}} \sum^n_{n=1} u_r$, so the sum of the time domain vector divided by the square root of the number of points. In my case, it just happens that since all my points are positive, I end up with a large zeroth frequency value.

The math still works out. When I apply that the zeroth frequency $v_1$ is related to the amplitude via $\sqrt{n}$: $v_1=A_0\sqrt{n}$, then the 'offset' is equal to $A_0=\frac{v_1}{\sqrt{n}}$, or $A_0=\frac{\sum^n_{n=1}u_r}{n}$, which was part of my confusion regarding different scalings.